# Why do I need to enclose input in quote marks?

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on Python2.7.6 and came across the following problem:

```
x=eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
```

Here, the input is supposed to create a string, but it's not running unless I wrap input in single quote marks too, check out the following:

```
x=eval('input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")')
```

Can someone please clarify why the first code wasn't running and the second one worked? It's really frustrating...I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Its simpler to get input like: hobby = raw_input("Your hobby: ") or if you expect integer input like guess = int(raw_input("Your guess: ")). At least that is how Codecademy teaches it.

Comment: Not sure why you're using `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `input` is just the composition of `eval` and `raw_input`. In effect, your first line is:

```
x=eval(eval(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")))
```

Typing in `123` will result in the first call to `eval` passing the *integer* `123` into the second `eval` function, which throws a nice error:

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object
```

Typing in `'123'` will make the string pass through unmodified, since `eval("'123'") == '123'`. Since you don't want to evaluate anything, just use `raw_input`:

```
x = raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the option you suggested. I am working on John Zelle's Python Programming to teach myself some Python programming. He said that 'eval' is needed when the required user input is numeric in nature. In another example using a 'string' he omitted it altogether...Anyway, thanks for your response and explanation. I will try out your suggestion and see how that works!

Comment: @Soly: That's bad advice, honestly. If your input is an integer, use `int(raw_input('> '))`. If it's a float, use `float(...)`. You can almost always avoid using `eval`, which will do things that you don't expect it to.

Comment: @Soly: I've heard this book is alright: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex11.html